# Can we convert pdf to docx using iText 7 on .Net core?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext, docx

**I need to convert a pdf document to docx file**

The purpose is to extract *Headers, titles and paragraphs* present in the document

I have tried looking in the API documentation for classes that might possibly help to do this, but couldn't find it in the docs.

All help is appreciated

Comment: In general there aren't *Headers, titles and paragraphs* in a PDF anymore, at least not marked in a machine readable way. You can attempt to find and apply heuristics but they will generally fail more or less often. iText does offer extendable text extraction methods but they don't interpret the text. You can apply your heuristics to the outputs of those methods.

Comment: What is the source of the PDF? If the PDF is "Tagged" then this info might be in the PDF file. But, normally, as mkl said, PDF files normally do not contain any of this info, unless they happen to be Tagged PDF.

Comment: The pdfs which I'm using don't have well defined tags, they are research papers with headings, figures and tables. Thanks for the info

Comment: You could check out the leadtools pdf to docx converter: https://www.leadtools.com/blog/document-imaging/document-converter/convert-pdf-docdocx/ (disclaimer, I am a vender of this library)